# Delete comments on instagram media through instagram API

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I'm developing an instagram app. Everything was fine till I reached deleting comments from instagram media. Here is my request url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/[media_id]/comments?access_token=[access_token]
```

and post body

```
--xXxBoUnDaRyxXx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="comment_id"

309854812055300359
--xXxBoUnDaRyxXx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"

DELETE
--xXxBoUnDaRyxXx
```

I have tried to remove the `_method=DELETE` and set `httpmethod` to `DELETE`, but no luck. Server just returns empty data, no error, no meta information. Anybody tried and succeeded with this? Please, help.

**EDIT**
I have just discovered that server is returning response with code 405 - remote url returned error 405 method not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem with the help of Will https://github.com/wfleming/WFInstagramAPI/issues/1#issuecomment-9779870. Actually, I had to send DELETE request to the URL like https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments/{comment-id}?access_token=foo:. Instagram docs have to be updated.